# Machine Learning Textbook Recommendation for Mathematician

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning

I wonder if someone could recommend me some textbook (or recourse in general) on machine learning, suitable for mathematics students.

I am a student in pure math, specialized in real and functional analysis, I am also familiar with basic probability theories based on measure theory. I have no knowledge of computation theories however. I want to find a text that focuses on ML theory that uses precise and rigorous mathematical statements in terms of **axioms, definitions, theorems**, and **proofs**, as opposed to a more applicational manner focusing on specific codes.

In particular, I do not want text that spends half its length talking about basic definitions such as vector space or continuity/differentiability, rather some text that assumes reader's familiarity with mathematics.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do these link answer your request? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143402/introduction-to-machine-learning-for-mathematicians https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14396/data-science-machine-learning-books-for-mathematicians

Comment: thanks guys, I'll take a look at them